# error: use of undeclared identifier 'from_chars'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

This is a C++ file from my lecture recording; The instructor can compile the file with no problem with g++. He's using Ubuntu though, whereas I am using Mac, but I am not sure if that matters.

```cpp
#include <charconv>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 2)
    return 1;

  ifstream in(argv[1]);
  unsigned sum = 0;
  string line;
  while (getline(in, line)) {
    const char *last = nullptr;
    unsigned col = 0;
    for (char &c : line)
      if (c == '|') {
        ++col;
        if (col == 4) {
          last = (&c) + 1;
        } else if (col == 5) {
          unsigned v;
          from_chars(last, &c, v);
          sum += v;
          break;
        }
      }
  }
  cout << sum << endl;
}
```

I kept getting this error:

```
$ g++ sum1.cpp 
        
sum1.cpp:25:11: error: use of undeclared identifier 'from_chars'
          from_chars(last, &c, v);
          ^
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing? Thanks!

Comment: what gcc version do you have? from_chars was introduced in C++17

Comment: That's actually a [clang error message](https://godbolt.org/z/o8Kd6afcz). Gcc reports it differently (was not declared in this scope). Adding a `--std=c++14` or 17 option should help.

Comment: @dratenik `--std=c++14` won't work, has to be `--std=c++17` or higher

Comment: @RemyLebeau empirically both gcc and clang seem to accept the code at 14. I agree that it would be best to try 17 first as that is the official level for this feature, but if OP's compiler doesn't support that, 14 might be viable.